# Nepali Font Rendering Problem in Firefox

Tags: firefox, 14.04, fonts

I have installed so many nepali fonts in my computer. But firefox do not show all nepali fonts properly.

Answer (score 1):

- Open Firefox
- Go to `Preferences -> Content`
- In that window, click on `Advanced` button present beside `Fonts & Colors`
- A new popup window will appear
- In that window, select `Devanagari` in `Fonts for` select box
- Select `Lohit Devanagari` in `Serif`, `Sans-serif` and `Monospace` select boxes
- Click on `OK` button

Now, you should be able to see Nepali fonts properly rendered in your Firefox browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing ancient nepali fonts:

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to do apt-get update before

```
sudo apt-cache search nepali
```

This will show the available fonts. The result i got are:

```
firefox-esr-l10n-ne-np - Nepali (Nepal) language package for Firefox ESR
fonts-deva-extra - Free fonts for Devanagari script
scim-tables-additional - miscellaneous input method data tables for SCIM platform
task-nepali-desktop - Nepali desktop
task-nepali-kde-desktop - Nepali KDE Plasma desktop
tesseract-ocr-nep - tesseract-ocr language files for Nepali
```

Now install required fonts using following command

```
sudo apt-get install firefox-esr-l10n-ne-np fonts-deva-extra
```

I have installed **fonts-deva-extra** and **firefox-esr-l10n-ne-np** fonts. After refreshing browser the nepali fonts are shown properly